# Django Attribute error: "unicode object has no attribute tags"

Tags: python, django, attributeerror

Everything works quite well,so I presumed anyways but when I runserver and click the title of my blog,i get an AttributeError saying 'unicode object has no attribute tags'

heres the the piece of code handling the tags

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
     post_tags_ids = post.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
     similar_posts =  Post.published.filter(tags__in=post_tags_ids).exclude(id=post.id)                     
     similar_posts =  similar_posts.annotate(same_tags=Count('tags')).order_by('-same_tags','-publish')[:4]
     post = get_object_or_404(Post, slug=post,status='published',publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day)
     return render(request,'blog/post/detail.html',{'post': post,'comments': comments,'comment_form': comment_form,'similar_posts': similar_posts})
```

Comment: post is not the post instance. It is just the argument. You will have to get the object.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the 'post' argument you are passing is not a model instance as you presume. I think you need to fetch the post object first. Assuming you are passing pk as post:

```
post_object = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=post)
post_tags_ids = post_object.tags.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

Comment: but you have to send the post pk from the url

Comment: Actually what is this post which you get? Is it slug of the post or something?